# How to display image in table cell in python notebook

Tags: python, html, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to display some generated images with some texts in a table using pandas in jupyter notebook. I tried something like this:

```
import pandas
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pandas.DataFrame([plt.imshow(random.random((50,50))),plt.imshow(random.random((50,50)))])
display(df)
```

but I only get a table with the object name, not the actual images

[image]

So what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: plt.subplots().